# Javascript regex for email allowing '\' in email

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex for my email:

```
const EMAIL = /^(([^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

I want to validate below email as true:

```
Fred\ Bloggs@example.com true
Joe.\\Blow@example.com true
""test\\blah""@example.com true
```

Below email as false:
    ""test\blah""@example.com

currently, I'm not able to do this validation please help

Comment: The HTML(5) spec has a relatively simple regex for emails that native form validation uses (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address): `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/`. Probably it makes sense to reuse it for consistency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks for your reply https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/  want validation for this article

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /(([^<>()\[\].,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
var test_email1 ='""test\blah""@example.com"';
alert(validateEmail(test_email1));
var test_email2 ='Fred\ Bloggs@example.com';
alert(validateEmail(test_email2));
var test_email3 ='Joe.\\Blow@example.com';
alert(validateEmail(test_email3));
var test_email4 ='""test\\blah""@example.com';
alert(validateEmail(test_email4));
```

Comment: thinks it's passing most of test cases except ""test\blah""@example.com should give false and ""test\\blah""@example.com as true

Comment: this is"not\allowed@example.com it's passing this test case but should not pass as it has only one " .

Comment: looks like you changed the test case and remove the double quotes at the end of the false example. Just to be clear, it would be true if there is space after the single \ but it would be false if there is a \ and follow with a char or num?

Comment: my bad i changed it after i was i posted wrong test case

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function from [Omid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409041/6010917) using a regex that meets [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1).

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

console.log(validateEmail('Fred\ Bloggs@example.com')); // logs true
console.log(validateEmail('Joe.\\Blow@example.com')); // logs true
console.log(validateEmail('""test\\blah""@example.com')); // logs true
```

You'll notice this function doesn't return `false` on the case you'd like to fail.

The only way to really test an email address is to send an email to it -- don't rely on regex to verify email addresses because your regex will never be perfect.